# How to avoid a race condition when using cats-effect based workers?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scala-3, cats-effect

I created a tiny worker system to run parallel jobs with maximum multi-core processor utilization.
It seems to work fine, but at some point, when working with a larger amount of jobs, an error appears (no error message, just hangs), which I suspect to be a low-level race condition. I cannot decide whether this is the fault of cats-effect, which I use to implement parallelism, or Atomic or TrieMap.

Here's a minified implementation which can be used to illustrate and test the issue:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.{AtomicBoolean, AtomicLong}
import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap


object ThreadingError extends App:
  val jobIdsAdded = (0L until 10000L).toList
  for (_ <- jobIdsAdded.iterator) {
    ParallelJobs.addJob(() => {})
  }
  while(ParallelJobs.count.get() < 10000L) {
    print(s"${ParallelJobs.count.get()}\r")
    Thread.sleep(200)
  }

object ParallelJobs:
  private val allCores = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()
  private val availableCores = allCores - 1
  private val assignedTillJobId: AtomicLong = AtomicLong(0L)
  val jobsTrieMap: TrieMap[Long, () => Any] = TrieMap.empty[Long, () => Any]
  val jobsConcurrentHashMap: ConcurrentHashMap[Long, () => Any] = ConcurrentHashMap[Long, () => Any]()

  val locked: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)
  val count: AtomicLong = AtomicLong(0L)

  workerGroup
    .unsafeRunAsync(either => {
      if (either.isLeft)
        println(either.left.get.getMessage)
        either.left.get.printStackTrace()
    })

  def addJob(jobFn: () => Any): Unit =
    val jobId = jobsTrieMap.size
    jobsTrieMap(jobId) = jobFn
    //val jobId = jobsConcurrentHashMap.size()
    //jobsConcurrentHashMap.put(jobId, jobFn)

  private def workerGroup: IO[Unit] = (0 until availableCores).map(_ => worker).reduce(_ &> _)

  private def worker: IO[Unit] =
    IO({
      while (true) {
        if (!locked.get() && jobsTrieMap.nonEmpty)
        //if (!locked.get() && !jobsConcurrentHashMap.isEmpty)
          locked.set(true)
          val jobId = assignedTillJobId.getAndIncrement()
          val toDo = jobsTrieMap(jobId)
          //val toDo = jobsConcurrentHashMap.get(jobId)
          jobsTrieMap -= jobId
          //jobsConcurrentHashMap.remove(jobId)
          locked.set(false)
          toDo() // long running job
          count.incrementAndGet()
        else
          Thread.sleep(100)
      }
    })
```

As you can see, I also tried ConcurrentHashMap; using it simply stopped the app from running.
I came up with some locking mechanism to test whether the issue was caused by multiple workers trying to write the TrieMap, but that did not help either.

I use Scala 3.3 and cats-effect 3.5.1

Comment: What is the real meta-problem you are trying to solve here? Run multiple CPU intensive jobs in parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code doesn't seem to be aware of how the concept of `IO` type is supposed to work.

The idea behind all these IO types on Scala (Future, Cats Effect's IO, ZIO, Monix's Task...) is that you write kinda declarative code (and surely higher level than individual `Thread`s and locks) and it is send to a runner with a `Scheduler`. Since all of you code is supposed to be build with: `map`, `flatMap`, `recover`, `traverse`, and other combinations, the assumption is that each individual uninterruptible piece inside IO is:

- small/granular
- short-running
- NOT taking away the control from the runner

It allows the Scheduler to:

- control the parallelism!
- control when the job is scheduled
- and when it should be cancel (it simply NOT run the next operation defined by map/flatMap/etc, but create the error instead)

This means among others:

- no `Thread.sleep` - there are instructions to let the fiber sleep without blocking a whole `Thread` in a thread pool (and potentially blocking a whole thread pool with operations that `sleep` naively)
- no `while(true)` - because it hijacks a whole `Thread` and makes it impossible to cancel the operation (and w
- no blocking and locking - there are declarative ways of handling these operations which doesn't show the middle finger to a Thread pools, Executors and Schedulers (`Ref`s, `Semaphore`s, etc).

It doesn't mean that it is absolutely not possible to use these in with IO monads, just that these were constructed to make it easy to build concurrent app... as long as you use them, because they expects that you don't break the assumptions they are build upon (similarly to how you might have a bad experience in Spring Framework + Hibernate if you decide that `Thread` pinning is not a thing and start running you own thing on the side). So, messing around low-level is something I recommend waiting until you understand how the runtime works underneath.

Meanwhile, I recommend to rewrite this whole code to something which uses the build-in combinators and operations:

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import cats.syntax._

object ExampleApp extends IOApp.Simple {

  val run: IO[Unit] = (0L until 10000L)
    .toList
    // will be run in parallel!
    .parTraverse { number =>
      // sleep 2s then print
      IO.sleep(2000) >> IO {
        println(i)
      }
    }
    .void // makes result Unit
}
```

> I created a tiny worker system to run parallel jobs with maximum multi-core processor utilization

All of the monads for side effects: `scala.concurrent.Future`, `cats.effect.IO`, `monix.eval.Task`, `zio.ZIO` have a default `Scheduler` which uses `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` to decide the size of the `Thread` pool. And they are additionally aware of things like how to handle blocking (defined declaratively) in a way that prevents stucking all of the threads in "waiting" state where the job that could "notify" them cannot get to the thread pool. Or handling `SIGTERM` signals to cancel ongoing tasks but in a predicatable manner (jobs that need to finish could be made `uncancellable`, streams could be adjusted to safely finish processing that one task and then not take another, `Resource`s could be safely closed and cleaned, etc).

Meaning that the entirety of your code can be replaced with just some `parTraverse` or something to get the same result but without race conditions.

If you want to control the size of your parallelism more granularly, you can use:

- if you have a list of other finite collection of tasks then e.g.:

  ```
  IO.parSequenceN(listOfIOs)(sizeOfParallelism)
  ```
- if you have unbounded collection of data there are functional streams

  ```
  fs2.Stream
    .fromIterator[IO]((1 until 100).iterator, chunkSize)
    .mapAsync(sizeOfParallelism) { int =>
      IO.sleep(2000) >> IO {
        println(i)
      }
    }
  ```

Long story short: don't roll your own *low-level solution* (until you understand what the library does under the hood) and it will be fine. There is enough helpers to do roll your own solution *on top of the library's API* to deliver the same thing easier, faster and without race conditions or other issues.

Comment: In my specific use case, I'll definitely have long-running jobs with a computational need. I don't see how these jobs could be split any further; there will be a threshold below which I could not go, considering job sizes. If I do so, I'll end up sacrificing efficiency due to the nature of my data processing flow.
Also, I'll need to take into account that the running jobs will initiate concurrency that would be out of the control of Cats Effect's scheduler, hence it seemed a good solution to let while loop hijack the thread.

Comment: Though while(true) could be replaced with something like while(thisWorkerCanRun) to make it possible to stop from running.

Comment: It's very, very simple once you understand IO monad and for comprehension. Take a block inside a `while` and: turn every single  `doSomething` line into `_  <- IO(doSomething)`, every `val x = doSomething` into `x <- doSomething`. Then put `for {` line before, and `} yield ()` after. Finally, replace `while (true) { for comprehension }` with `def myProcess = (for comprehension).flatMap(_ => myProcess)`. Done, you have a recepe for a job running forgever with a granular control available to the Scheduler.

Comment: If you want to hijack a thread: create your own separate thread. No framework that I know in Scala OR Java responds well to hijacking THEIR threads.

Comment: And if you want to control concurrency, there are still better methods that low lever: Java has build in Thread pools (single, fixed, fork join etc).

Comment: Basically, I'll need to create a snippet that creates an arbitrary number of Futures and nothing more is needed, at least for my use case

Comment: If that's true then you simply need to create the `Future`s with `Future.Implicit.global` imported and `blocking {}` around the blocking part of code. And if you need to `while (true)` create it in a `new Thread`. However, I am almost certain that you are doing premature optimization.

Comment: The reason I needed to check these aspects is that necessary data processing for testing was running too long on my laptop, therefore I decided to look into these parts to speed it up even in early development.

Comment: JMH, async-profiler, flight recorder, Java Mission Control - without them you almost certainly optimize the wrong thing.